# List of Google Plus People contacts returns 0

Tags: c#, google-plus, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to fetch the list of people in all the circles of a user's Google plus account.
I am using the Google People API but the list always returns 0.
The code is as below:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin,
            PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail,
            PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile};
string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
 UserCredential credential =
                    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "someid",
                        ClientSecret = "somekey"
                    },
                                                                scopes,
                                                                Environment.UserName,
                                                                CancellationToken.None,
                                                            new FileDataStore(credPath,true)
                                                                ).Result;


            PlusService service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "Google Plus Sample",
            });

            PeopleResource.ListRequest listPeople = service.People.List("me", PeopleResource.ListRequest.CollectionEnum.Visible);
            listPeople.MaxResults = 10;
            PeopleFeed peopleFeed =  listPeople.Execute();
```

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow[SO]`, please be a bit more specific [when asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): What have you tried so far with code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get?

Comment: i am expecting the list of people for the authenticated user. The id has people in various circles in google plus account. I dont receive any errors as well. All it does is returns a list of count 0

Comment: Then write it in your question, the more specific you are, the more user can help you! I can't help you, but I can give you tips to improve your question quality :) And if you haven't read it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) than do this right know.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation for [people.list](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list) you can see that this method doesnt work anymore.

> The Google+ People API list endpoint is deprecated. Consider using the Google People API instead.

You can try and switch to the google people api but this is not a list of the users on Google+ IIR its a list of peolpe the user has setup in Google contacts.

Comment: I tried the same and it returns me an error.
An exception of type 'Google.GoogleApiException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

Unable to find user with ID: people/me [404]

Comment: are you using a service account?  Have the user login here make sure they have a google account https://contacts.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes i am using the "PlusService", i tried fetching Activities and it gives me results for the same service i created but nothing in the "People"

Comment: Check update I thought you were using a diffrent method.

Comment: Thanks! So is there any other way to get the list of GooglePlus people list in various circles. I am planning to make an "Invite Friends" module in my web app. Any other suggestion is always welcomed. :-)